# add directory to shell profile

Tags: bash, shell, profile, konsole

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a program executable from everywhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/how-can-i-make-a-program-executable-from-everywhere)

So, I'm new to Linux/Unix and am working in a corporate version of Red Hat at my company. Obviously I don't have full control over my computer (not sure if that matters).

I have a bunch of executables located in some folder.

I want to be able to run these programs from any other directory.

How can I make this happen? Some sort of bash profile file maybe? If so, where would that be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you add the /path/to/executables to the `$PATH` variable, to make this a default setting you add it to one of `bash`'es startup files, `.bash_profile` is probably the most appropriate one. Add the following line to `$HOME/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/path/to/executables"
```

Or if a `PATH` line already exists in `.bash_profile`, append or prepend `/path/to/executables` to it. Each of the path elements are searched in order, so if you want to override some commands, put your path first.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't understand how to do this. When I type in the export PATH command: 'export PATH="$PATH:"/ep/home/eniven/gslib1/"', then I get an error "Bad : modifier in $ (/)". When I type the command:'export PATH="$PATH:"ep/home/eniven/gslib1"', I get the error: export: command not found. When I look in the directory /home/, there is nothing in there (no hidden files either) and I do not have write access to that directory.

Comment: PATH needs to be protected from parameter expansion, you can do this with curly braces, see update to answer.