# Automating pipes?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, pipe

I find myself using basically the same line over and over again:

```
cat file | command1 | command2 | command3 > file
```

Is there a way I can put all these pipes into one script, so I can just run

```
automatic.sh file
```

and accomplish the same thing?

Comment: with `> file`, even before any of the `cat`, `command1`, `command2` or `command3` is started, the shell will have truncated `file`. So `cat` will see an empty file.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas is right, you will **destroy** your data because ` file` will be emptied!

Answer (score 4):

Create a file with this content:

```
command1 | command2 | command3
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x that-file
```

And call it as:

```
/path/to/that-file < file.in > file.out
```

Add `/path/to` to your `$PATH` variable in order to be able to do:

```
that-file < file.in > file.out
```

Answer (score 3):

automatic.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | command1 | command2 | command3 > .automatic.sh.temp
rm $1
mv .automatic.sh.temp $1
```

then call it like:

```
automatic.sh file
```

to use a real example:

```
arthur@a:~$ cat automatic.sh 
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | grep foo | sed -e 's/foo/bar/g' | sort > $1

arthur@a:~$ cat <<END > foo
> 1 foo
> 2 bar
> 3 foo
> 4 bat
> 5 foo
> END
arthur@a:~$ chmod +x automatic.sh 
arthur@a:~$ ./automatic.sh foo
arthur@a:~$ cat foo
1 bar
3 bar
5 bar
```

And just to be pedantic, it's slightly better form to write the output to a temporary file, then at the end move the tempfile over the original file.

Comment: yes, that was a bug. fixed :)

Comment: [it produces empty file whatever the input.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103904/automating-pipes#comment158987_103904)

Comment: does the example in the original question behave the same? They should both have the same race condition between the end of the pipe and the beginning, hence my comment about using a temporary file and a move at the end.

Comment: It's not just “slightly better form”. Depending on chance, the file may be truncated before it is read. `cat file | … >file` does not work reliably.

Comment: in your very top code block, I don't think you need that `rm` call. wouldn't the `mv` just overwrite `$1`?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a script or function that contains this command. Use `"$1`" to refer to the first argument passed to the script or function.

There's a major bug in your code snippet: depending on the timing, `> file` may truncate the file before the first command in the pipeline starts reading the file, or shortly after it starts reading. Your snippet may occasionally work with small files, but most of the time it won't work.

The recommended way to modify a file is to write to a new temporary file, and once this is finished, move it to replace the old version. This way, if something bad happens to interrupt the processing (such as an error, a power failure, etc.), the old file remains in place.

Here is a function that operates on this principle. Thanks to the `&&` after the pipeline, it only moves the output file into place if `command3` returns a success status (note that the return status of other commands in the pipeline is ignored). I rely on the common `mktemp` utility to create the temporary file (it ensures that the name of the temporary file won't collide with any other instance of the script or any other program).

```
my_pipeline () {
  out=$(TMPDIR=$(dirname -- "$1") mktemp)
  <"$1" command1 | command2 | command3 >"$out" &&
  mv -f "$out" "$1"
}
```

Put this function in your `.bashrc`; it will be available the next time you start bash. You can also copy-paste the definition on the command line to have it take effect in that shell. To use it, type the name of the function and then the name of the file to act on:

```
my_pipeline my_file
```

You can make the function act on all of its arguments in turn by putting that stuff in a loop.

```
my_pipeline () {
  for file; do
    out=$(TMPDIR=$(dirname -- "$file") mktemp)
    <"$file" command1 | command2 | command3 >"$out" &&
    mv -f "$out" "$file"
  done
}
```

Usage:

```
my_pipeline file1 file2 file3
```

If you want to make a script instead, put the code in a file starting with a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to indicate that it's a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file; do
  out=$(TMPDIR=$(dirname -- "$file") mktemp)
  <"$file" command1 | command2 | command3 >"$out" &&
  mv -f "$out" "$file"
done
```

Put the file in your command search path and make it executable (see [How can I make a program executable from everywhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/how-can-i-make-a-program-executable-from-everywhere/3822#3822)).

Another way to solve the truncate-before-use problem is the [sponge](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) utility, but this utility isn't available everywhere (it's from Debian).

Comment: `sponge` is from http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/, it's not debian specific.

Comment: You may want to consider symlinks separately.

Comment: And check the exit status of mktemp