# How to get command line flags or options in an executable command program

Tags: command-line, command, arguments, c++

I made a practice C++ program that generates a new password everytime I execute it, it asks me for the password length and then proceeds to generate a new pseudorandom password.

I will add its directory to the PATH environment variable so I can execute it from any directory.

I want to know how I can modify the executable to get the command line arguments, so I can invoke it from the terminal in the following manner:

`newpass -10`
or
`newpass 10`

Both of these would generate a password of 10 characters. I currently have my program as an object file that I have to execute as:

`./newpass`

Comment: If you want to pass arguments to your C++ program, you'll need to use a suitable library. This is really more of a programming question, and would be on topic on SO. But there should definitely be information available about this on the net already.

Comment: Do a Google search for "C++ argument parsing library". It will give you some hits. http://tclap.sourceforge.net/ seems popular. Though to a first approximation, you can just use something primitive like argv[].

Comment: Thank you. I only just realized I was looking at it with the wrong approach. I found: Example of Parsing Arguments with getopt. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html

Comment: BTW if these passwords are for actually securing anything (as opposed to learning how to program) make sure you are using a suitably strong and valid CSPRNG or TRNG. If for example you're just calling `rand()` then a competent adversary can easily figure out all your generated passwords. For questions in that area go to security.SX

Comment: It's a programming question that  has nothing to do with Unix/Linux

Answer (score 1):

`Getopt` is a little overkill to just get one command line argument.  If your program requires more options and arguments later, you might consider something else similar to `getopt`.  For a more C++ oriented way to parse more complicated command lines you might want to take a look at the [Boost Program Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/program_options.html) library.  Most languages (Java, Perl, Python, C, C++, Pascal, etc etc) have a library of functions or statements which return the command line arguments.

In C or C++ you can simply convert the first argument "10" or whatever it is, to an integer.  All command line arguments are strings (`char` arrays terminated with a zero byte).

Something like this:

1. Add the code to your main program to check for the command line argument, something like:

   ```
   int pwlength(10); // or whatever the default
   if (argc > 1) {
        // put code here to convert the string in argv[0] to an integer
        // and store in pwlength.
        // If the string cannot be converted,
        //    Print an error message and exit the program with
        //    the statement "return 1;" or "exit(1);" which
        //    notifies the caller of the executable that an error occurred.
    }
   std::cout << "Your password length will be: " << pwlength << std::endl;
   ```
2. Add the *directory* where the file `newpass` is stored to your `PATH` variable, for example, assuming `newpass` is located in your `$HOME/bin` directory:
   `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"`
3. Change the file modes of the file `newpass` with `chmod`:
   `chmod +x newpass`

Comment: Thank you very much I was looking into it and you are right. I always wondered how the GNU programs received their arguments and I thought it had more to do with the shell.

Comment: Great. In Unix & Linux, the shell expands the command line for shell variables, file name matching patterns, etc, and then puts them in an array that gets copied into your program's argument vector (argv).

Comment: I'd make a distinction: those languages (except Pascal AFAIK) automatically receive the _arguments_; they often use libraries to parse _options_ which, if used at all, are often a subset of the arguments. Also, in C and C++ `argv[0]` is the name of the program and `argv[1]` is the first argument (if it exists). Java args and perl ARGV start at 0; python starts at 1 but has no 0.

Answer (score -1):

Shamelessly copied from here: [How can I make a program executable from everywhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/how-can-i-make-a-program-executable-from-everywhere)

"If you just type export `PATH=$PATH:</path/to/file>` at the command line it will only last for the length of the session.

If you want to change it permanently add export `PATH=$PATH:</path/to/file>` to your ~/.bashrc file (just at the end is fine)." -oadams

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I had already stumbled upon that question and that's why I stated I would add the add it's path. But I want to know how to make it executable with flags.